# How to send body through xmlhttprequest for a POST request?

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest, postman, basic-authentication

I am trying to send a POST xmlhttprequest for Basic Authentication request. The response is an auth token which i need to use. I am defining the username and password and also sending a body. But whenever i execute the below code through Javascript, it gives me a 401 error. But when i send a request through postman, it gives me the expected output. I even tried taking the code directly from postman but it still gives me a 401 error. Below is the code i am executing -

```
var jsonToSend = {
            'grant_type':'client_credentials'
          };
    var client_id= 'usernameTest';
    var secret_key= 'PasswordTest';
    var token_url = 'urlTest';
                 
                let xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr2.open("POST",token_url);
                //xhr2.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic "+btoa(client_id+":"+secret_key));
                xhr2.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic "+(client_id+":"+secret_key));
              

               xhr2.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
               //xhr2.send(jsonToSend);

              /* xhr2.send(JSON.stringify({
                 'grant_type':'client_credentials'
               }));*/
              xhr2.send("grant_type=client_credentials");
```

I have tried sending the body in different formats (which i have commented out in the above code) but it gives me a 401 error everytime.

Below is the postman generated code -

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic btoa");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");

var requestOptions = {
method: 'POST',
headers: myHeaders,
body: urlencoded,
redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("urlTest", requestOptions)
.then(response => response.text())
.then(result => console.log(result))
.catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

The postman code also gives 401 error when i try to execute it in my Javascript file. But in postman, POST call works properly.
I am sorry i cannot give out the credentials and url. I feel this is an issue in the way i am sending the body (which is grant_type:client_credentials).

Below is the screenshot from postman.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `URLSearchParams` or `FormData`? It looks like you're not actually url-encoding the body data.

Comment: "*The postman code also gives 401 error when i try to execute it in my Javascript file*" - can you show the actual postman request then, not the js code generated from it?

Comment: Also, are there any CORS-related error messages? Is the URL on the same domain as your javascript, are you restricted by the SOP?

Comment: What is `"Basic btoa"`, is that a placeholder for the actual value? How is the actual value generated? If the server is following the standard, you should definitely use `"Basic "+btoa(client_id+":"+secret_key)`, not the version without base64 (`btoa`).

Comment: Did you do some debugging in the network panel of your browser's developer tools? What is the actual request that is sent? Does it include all the headers that you passed? Does it look like the working postman one?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that im using btoa only in the code, i just pasted the code without btoa since i was trying to see if it works without btoa.

Comment: i have added the screenshot from postman also.